# Изменение класса дива по клику на чекбокс

Tags: javascript, css

Есть такой простенький код:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/><label for="ckeckbox">Click me!</label>
 <div class="hide-div">Hello, world!</div>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы по клику на чекбокс div менял свой свой класс с "hide-div" на "view-div". Как это реализовать на чистом js, желательно, без подключения jQuery и чтобы этот код работал без ошибки хотя бы в 8 IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/cLUJK/). Хотя, на jQuery - это всё сделать было бы гораздо проще.

Comment: Посмотрел одним глазом, вроде работает. По крайней мере в Сафари точно. Спасибо.